# deploying multiple servers that communicate with each other, best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, capistrano, thin

Say I have:

- a Rails app that I want to deploy to Server A
- a Sinatra app that I want to deploy to Server B
- the Rails app needs to communicate with the Sinatra app

I can set up a config file that Capistrano reads to deploy both apps.  I can put a config file on Server A that the Rails app reads telling the Rails app that the Sinatra app on Server B.  But is there a best-practices way to automate this whole process?

thanks in advance, Chuck

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go for this is using messaging.If you don't know it's a technology for managing asynchronus services( aka apps).

It means that even someone you has lot of apps like you do messaging make them talk to each other, and if one of them break, the messaging technology will put the data on a queue so it'll not be lost.

There's several source of information for messaging.But first of all I advice you to pick 
[Paul dix's](http://www.amazon.fr/Service-Oriented-Design-Ruby-Rails-Paul/dp/0321659368/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1323986689&sr=8-2) book which is a major source of information to get start.

Also go to [Rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) which is one of the most advanced messaging technology out there.

But remember that your configuration will need much work upfront.But once it's done you'll cool.

That was my humble contribution.

Ps: I'm not an expert, as you I'm trying to implement this kind of architecture too.